# Android RxJava sort object by its parameter which is list of another object

Tags: android, kotlin, rx-java

I have an object

```
data class Question(
    var publishDate: DateTime?,
    var tags: List<QuestionTags>
    etc.
```

Now it's sorted by publishDate
`val sortedQuestions = questions.sortedBy { it.publishDate }`

But I would like to sort it by one of its tags `chapterId`. QuestionTags looks like this

```
data class QuestionTags(
    val id: Long,
    val chapterId: Long?
    etc.
```

I was trying to do some RxJava magic

```
sortedQuestions = 
   questions.flatMap { it.tags }
      .filter { it.chapterId != null }
      .map { sortedQuestions[0] }
      .sortedBy { it.blablabla }
```

But it isn't working in any case.

How to `.map` it or `.flatMap` it to make it happen?

I was trying to flatMap it to QuestionTags, than map it to `Question`

```
sortedQuestions =
   questions.flatMap { it.tags }
   .filter { it.chapterId != null }
   .map { Question() }
```

But in `.map { Question() }` it force me to pass values to all constructor parameters, which I don't want to do.

Comment: Since you have a `List<QuestionTags>`, what should happen if one question has tags with `chapterId` 1 and 3, and another with 2: which one should be sorted later? What if one has 1, 2, 3 and another 1,2?

Comment: It should be sorted by first chapterId from list.
And if both have same chapterId, they should be sorted by publishDate, like it's already done.

Answer (score 0):

> It should be sorted by first chapterId from list. And if both have same chapterId, they should be sorted by publishDate, like it's already done

Then you don't need `flatMap` (or RxJava) at all:

```
questions.sortedBy { Pair(it.tags.firstOrNull(), it.publishDate) }
```